# How does Ubuntu keep track of the "System restart required" flag in motd?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a few Ubuntu servers (8.10, 9.10) that is set to automatically install security updates. Some times these updates requires a restart of the system, and this string is shown in `motd`:

```
*** System restart required ***
```

To get a notice about these, I plan to write a Nagios test to monitor if the server is in need of a reboot. So, my question:

Is there a better way than parsing `/etc/motd` to find out if a reboot is needed?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Check for the presence of `/var/run/reboot-required`.

Comment: Note: for debian systems, `/var/run/reboot-required` does not get created unless the `update-notifier-common` package is installed.

Comment: Note that [`update-notifier-common`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=update-notifier-common) has been removed in Debian Jessie. [`unattended-upgrades`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=unattended-upgrades) now includes a simple script `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades` which `touch`es the file. [`reboot-notifier`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=reboot-notifier) is another small package which is compatible with the format of `update-notifier-common`.

Comment: You may also want to check your running processes to see if a reboot has already been initiated. For instance, unattended-upgrades has the option of specifying a time for rebooting; until this time, the method above will continue to indicate that a reboot is required, even though one has already been initiated.

Answer (score 39):

The script that generates the reboot required part of motd is /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# helper for update-motd

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        cat /var/run/reboot-required
fi
```

Your nagios check could check for the existence of /var/run/reboot-required.

Comment: +1 for showing which file this is located in

Comment: that shell script isn't generating anything. It displays the contents if it exists

Answer (score 31):

Additionally the file '/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs' lists the packages that requested the reboot. For example:

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 
linux-image-2.6.32-28-generic
dbus
$
```

On Ubuntu Lucid (10.4).

Comment: Freaking thank you oh my god I missed that so much!

Answer (score 13):

Debian and Ubuntu packages can trigger the creation of `/var/run/reboot-required*` in their `postinst` file by executing the helper script `/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required`

Thus the "official" way to process reboots is handled by the package maintainer. I have been doing it previously in a script by comparing time booted against mtimes in /boot.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        # no reboot required (0=OK)
        echo "OK: no reboot required"
        exit 0
else
        # reboot required (1=WARN)
        echo "WARNING: `cat /var/run/reboot-required`"
        exit 1
fi
```