# how to check if an update will restart a service

Tags: debian, apt, update

I have a server which runs Debian 8. I wish to install various security updates however, prior doing so, i would like to know if any of the updates will restart a running service.

Is there a way (command - script) which can help me found out if a package will restart any process-daemon?

I would like to pinpoint here that i am interested **if an update will automatically restart a service** and not if a service requires a reboot after the update.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/667076/debian-how-can-i-know-if-reboot-is-required-after-update

Comment: They all do. How else would the security update begin to run?

Comment: My goal is to find out if an updated will automatically restart a service and not if an update will require a reboot